# Program doesn't work after making exe file by pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, sympy, sys

I made a Python program using numpy, sympy, sys which worked well in IDE. Here is the code...

```
import numpy as np
from sympy import *
import sys

f = open("result.txt", 'w+')
for line in sys.stdin:
    f.write(line)
f.close()
f = open("result.txt", 'r')
data = f.read().split("\n")
i = 0
while i < len(data):
    data[i] = data[i].split(' ')
    i += 1
print(data)
amount = int(data[0][0])
print(amount)
matrix = np.zeros((amount, amount))
i = 0
j = 0

while i < amount:
    while j < amount:
        matrix[i, j] = int(data[i + 1][j])
        j += 1
    j = 0
    i += 1
i = 0
j = 0
counter = 0
formula = 1
while i < amount:
    while j < amount:
        if matrix[i, j] == 1:
            x = symbols(str(i + 1))
            y = symbols(str(j + 1))
            if counter == 0:
                formula = (~x | ~y)
                counter += 1
            else:
                formula = formula & (~x | ~y)
        j += 1
    j = 0
    i += 1
formula_to_string = pycode(simplify_logic(formula, form='dnf', force=True))
massive_to_parse = formula_to_string.split("or")
k = 1
i = 0
while i < len(massive_to_parse):
    print("{", end='')
    while k < amount + 1:
        try:
            massive_to_parse[i].index(str(k))
        except ValueError:
            print("V",k, sep='', end='')
        finally:
            k += 1
    print("}-максимальное внутренне устойчивое множество")
    k = 1
    i += 1
```

Then I made an exe file using pyinstaller with this command...

```
pyinstaller main.py
```

but when i launch it, this errors appear.
[image: Error]

How can I fix this problem? Because I need exe file for university to launch it from other program on C

Comment: I've just created an Anaconda python3 environment (not that any of this would be Anaconda-specific) with numpy+sympy+pyinstaller, I've used  `pyinstaller --onefile r1.py` (btw here's [the fine documentation](https://readthedocs.org/projects/pyinstaller/downloads/pdf/stable/) for pyinstaller). I got back a 240MB .exe binary that ran just fine.

Comment: @wsdookadr, sorry, can't you please try create .exe with my code? I can't understand why it doesn't work for me...Maybe problem with sys library? And getting data from stdin

Comment: WARNING: Hidden import "pkg_resources.py2_warn" not found!
17086 WARNING: Hidden import "pkg_resources.markers" not found! That's what pyinstaller says

Comment: @wsdookadr, can I ask you what version of python do u use? Maybe it's because of python 3.9?

Comment: I used python 3.7